# Tree View Checkbox Expand collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to add expand collapse effect , but its not working :(

```
Here is my fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pervez/udc8f/6/

EDIT:

I also want to place these 'li' side by side in two column

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working ? error ? tell what expected result should be ?

Comment: I have sub checkbox inside main checkbox , when we click on main checkbox the subtree have to expand and collapse .

Comment: first structure your tree view properly,then think of animation and effects. your tree view appears broken. keep it simple

Comment: your code contain some errors ... pls check again ... (<li><input type='checkbox' class="cus" name='' id='chk_7'' value='1'><label>option1</label></li>) DOUBLE QUOTES !!! .. and notice ... you cant use the ID itentifier as multiple on one page. Is a unique. Duplicity as chk_7 on one page are not allowed and js can stop working!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pervez/udc8f/8/ it look something like this , the option input must be collapsed , showed only when we click on main checkbox , else collpase

Comment: I have update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pervez/udc8f/9/

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `id='chk_7''` have an extra `'`.  You could see it clearly in the jsfiddle syntax highlighting.
2. You better wrap the checkbox inside the label (will make label clicks work as checkbox clicks)
3. It works a bit better but only when you click the `<li>` not the checkbox.

There were several other small bugs, and some bugs remaining. You better practice debugging (ie. setting breakpoints, stepping the code, etc.). I changed it to handle checkbox clicks and few fixes here: http://jsfiddle.net/jjfaB/4/. Its still not perfect but you should be doing your own debugging...

Comment: I wann add pic if contains sub categories inside main categories .HOw can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple example of tree view I've made for you. It basically shows you to organize your code. If you cannot see it clearly, how can you manipulate it.

Super simple implementation

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.parent >ul').each(function(){ $(this).hide();});

            $('.parent >label').click(function(){

               $(this).parent().find('ul').each(function(){  
                  $(this).toggle();

               });
            });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class='parent'>
        <label value="*">*</label><input type="checkbox" value="" />
        <ul>
           <li><input type="checkbox" value="" class="child"/></li>
           <li><input type="checkbox" value="" class="child"/></li>
           <li><input type="checkbox" value="" class="child"/></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='parent'>
        <label value="*">*</label><input type="checkbox" value="" />
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="" class="child"/></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="" class="child"/></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
</body>
</html>
```

you can enhance to n-levels of node, animation, Id wise retrieval, 
different color at each level and what not..

Comment: its there; again click on the main checkbox. see the code, its 'toggle()'. wat it does is to toggle the display. hide to show, show to hide

Comment: even if we click on subcategories its toggling :( it must toggle only when we click on parent checkbox right?

Comment: also instead of input type='checkbox', you can use spans or divs with a look like checkboxex and place n image(tick mark, or green square). think abt it

Comment: that's because, see the click handler, it's bound to the entire parent li, so anywhere you click on the li (on the children), its click is called. you can place a label beside the parent checkboxes and bind click events to them. perhaps this is too simple a demo.

Comment: I've modified the code. now try it. and please look at the code.

Comment: Nice one manish...sucha small piece of code for treeview. Got it updated for my future projects use :P http://jsfiddle.net/NxQPv/2/

Answer (score -1):

I have usedjstree for one of my project. http://luban.danse.us/jazzclub/javascripts/jquery/jsTree/reference/_examples/4_themes.html  ..check if it helps for you.

Comment: Example page is not found